# How to test @Cacheable?

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing, spring-test

I am struggling with testing @Cacheable within a Spring Boot Integration Test. This is my second day learning how to do Integration Tests and all of the examples I have found use older versions. I also saw an example of `assetEquals("some value", is())` but nothing with an import statement to know which dependency "is" belongs to. The test fails at the second

This is my integration test....

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest // used for other methods
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
@SqlGroup({
        @Sql(executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,
                scripts = "classpath:data/Setting.sql") })
public class SettingRepositoryIT {

    @Mock
    private SettingRepository settingRepository;

    @Autowired
    private Cache applicationCache;


    @Test
    public void testCachedMethodInvocation() {
        List<Setting> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
        Setting settingOne = new Setting();
        settingOne.setKey("first");
        settingOne.setValue("method invocation");
        firstList.add(settingOne);

        List<Setting> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
        Setting settingTwo = new Setting();
        settingTwo.setKey("second");
        settingTwo.setValue("method invocation");
        secondList.add(settingTwo);

        // Set up the mock to return *different* objects for the first and second call
        Mockito.when(settingRepository.findAllFeaturedFragrances()).thenReturn(firstList, secondList);

        // First invocation returns object returned by the method
        List<Setting> result = settingRepository.findAllFeaturedFragrances();
        assertEquals("first", result.get(0).getKey());

        // Second invocation should return cached value, *not* second (as set up above)
        List<Setting> resultTwo = settingRepository.findAllFeaturedFragrances();
        assertEquals("first", resultTwo.get(0).getKey()); // test fails here as the actual is "second."

        // Verify repository method was invoked once
        Mockito.verify(settingRepository, Mockito.times(1)).findAllFeaturedFragrances();
        assertNotNull(applicationCache.get("findAllFeaturedFragrances"));

        // Third invocation with different key is triggers the second invocation of the repo method
        List<Setting> resultThree = settingRepository.findAllFeaturedFragrances();
        assertEquals(resultThree.get(0).getKey(), "second");
    }
}
```

ApplicationContext, components, entities, repositories and service layer for tests. The reason why I do it this way is because this maven module  is used in other modules as a dependency.

```
@ComponentScan({ "com.persistence_common.config", "com.persistence_common.services" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.persistence_common.entities" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.persistence_common.repositories" })
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Cache config....

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    public static final String APPLICATION_CACHE = "applicationCache";

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean registerOpenSessionInViewFilterBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter filter = new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter();
        registrationBean.setFilter(filter);
        registrationBean.setOrder(5);
        return registrationBean;
    }


    @Bean
    public Cache applicationCache() {
        return new GuavaCache(APPLICATION_CACHE, CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .build());
    }
}
```

The repository under test....

```
public interface SettingRepository extends JpaRepository<Setting, Integer> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM Setting WHERE name = 'featured_fragrance'")
    @Cacheable(value = CacheConfig.APPLICATION_CACHE, key = "#root.methodName")
    List<Setting> findAllFeaturedFragrances();
}
```

Comment: `is(...)` will most probably relate to [Hamcrest CoreMatcher's `is`](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.java#L104). Hamcrest is often used in combination with JUnits `assertThat(actual, matcher)` as it provides a more fluent reading-style of the assertions. I also [asked a question regarding Spring cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562642/caching-of-nested-cacheable-operation-via-springcache) some time ago where I used a unit test to depict my issue. Maybe it is helpful to you in some way

Comment: ok thank you Roman...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first problem with **SettingRepositoryIT** is, the **@Mock** anotation on the field **settingRepository**. This is paradox for any normal-test, integration-test or any else.

You should let Spring bring in the dependencies for the *class-under-test*, which is **SettingRepository** in your case.

Please look at this example how **@Autowired** is used for the *class-under-test*, which is **OrderService** in this example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
// ApplicationContext will be loaded from the
// static nested Config class
@ContextConfiguration
public class OrderServiceTest {

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        // this bean will be injected into the OrderServiceTest class
        @Bean
        public OrderService orderService() {
            OrderService orderService = new OrderServiceImpl();
            // set properties, etc.
            return orderService;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @Test
    public void testOrderService() {
        // test the orderService
    }

}
```

Go for the documentation with the full example: [§ 15. Integration Testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html)

The second problem is that you do not have to test @Cachable. You should only test your implementation. Here is a very good example from Oliver Gierke on how you should test it: [How to test Spring's declarative caching support on Spring Data repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221569/how-to-test-springs-declarative-caching-support-on-spring-data-repositories)

Comment: It's not correct that "you do not have to test Cachable", to feel safe I should have tools to test Cachable. If not, how can I be sure that all my JPA cache settings are correct? All needed annotations are in place? All the cache beans are in the container at run-time? I cannot trust it without testing. Anyways I will test Cachable with Spring Test or without it by making test example. I feel like not having the possibility to test it with SpringTest is a disadvantage.

Comment: What about [Cannot test Spring Caching in Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69313791/cannot-test-spring-caching-in-unit-test)?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to validate the expression in the unless expression in the @Cacheable annotation, so I think it makes perfect sense and I'm not testing Spring's code.

I managed to test it without using Spring Boot, so it is plain Spring test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyTest {

    private static MyCacheableInterface myCacheableInterfaceMock = mock(MyCacheableInterface.class);

    @Configuration
    @EnableCaching
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        public MyCacheableInterface myCacheableInterface() {
            return myCacheableInterfaceMock;
        }

        @Bean
        public CacheManager cacheManager() {
            return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("myObject");
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private MyCacheableInterface myCacheableInterface;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        when(myCacheableInterfaceMock.businessMethod(anyString())).then(i -> {
            List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(new MyObject(new Result("Y")));
            return list;
        });
        myCacheableInterface.businessMethod("test");
        verify(myCacheableInterfaceMock).businessMethod(anyString());
        myCacheableInterface.businessMethod("test");
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(myCacheableInterfaceMock);
    }
}
```

In MyCacheableInterface I have the following annotation:

```
public interface MyCacheableInterface {
    @Cacheable(value = "myObject", unless = "#result.?[Result.getSuccess() != 'Y'].size() == #result.size()")
    List<MyObject> businessMethod(String authorization);
}
```

Comment: What is `createTestResult()` ?

Comment: What about **[Cannot test Spring Caching in Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69313791/cannot-test-spring-caching-in-unit-test)** ?

Comment: I have replaced the createTestResult method by a proper Mock.

Comment: @What do you mean Chico?

Comment: In the first question you asked what is the method createTestResult(). That was supposed to be a mock that would have to be created to complete the code. I have updated the code to use Mockito to create the mock. It is not called directly, and instead it is called via myCacheableInterface which is created by Spring.