# @Cacheable annotation working not properly in Spring

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I encountered a strange behaviour while using `@Cacheable` annotation in Spring.
I have a method marked as `@Cacheable` and that returns Map:

```
//dao layer
@Cacheable(value = "Cache1")
public Map<String, String> getNamesByDateAndCurrency(LocalDate date, String currency) {
    // Returns some map
}
```

I call this method from the following method and change the map using the `retainAll()` method:

```
//service layer
@Autowired
private DaoImpl dao;
...
@Cacheable( value = "Cache2")
public List<Integer> getUUIDs(Integer requestNumber, Set<String> set) {
   //some code..
   Map<String, String> names = dao.getNamesByDateAndCurrency(params..);
   names.keySet().retainAll(set);
   //some other code, no any changes of map in further
}
```

`dao.getNamesByDateAndCurrency(params..)` expression returns, as expected, the cached data if I call this method a second time with the same parameters.

The problem is that the `getNamesByDateAndCurrency` method is caching the data changed after performing the `retainAll` method.

My question is why an external action (`retainAll`) method affects the cached response? Why hasn't it returned original data from `getNamesByDateAndCurrency` method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because it is basically the same object reference. It doesn't give you a copy of the object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caching of nested cacheable operation via SpringCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562642/caching-of-nested-cacheable-operation-via-springcache)

Comment: @RomanVottner this isn't a duplicate of that question

Comment: @pvpkiran I get it but why the data updated in cache by external operation (retainAll) on the object reference? Why data didn't cached while call getNamesByDateAndCurrency method and then no any cache updates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring cache stores the result in the cache by reference. Then, the caching framework used (Ehcache in your case I think) will store the result according to its configuration. Most frameworks will store it by reference by default because it is much faster.

You have 2 solutions:

1. Code in an immutable way. So when receiving the map, instead of modifying it in place, just create a copy. You can make sure of it by wrapping the result in a `Collections.unmodifiableMap`
2. Tell Ehcache to store by value. This is a bit more involved because you need to be able to [copy](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.4/serializers-copiers.html#copiers) the value. But it will work transparently

Note that whether you are storing data on the heap, on disks or clustered, it would work as expected by default. Because all these options require to copy the key and the value. Only on-heap has a "by reference" storage optimization.