# Cacheable and jUnit, looks like first is ignored

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spring-test

I'm trying to test @Cacheable an for now i have some problem, 
It's looks like jUnit and spring context just ignore @Cacheable annotation

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {ConfigConfigurationTest.class})
public class ConfigurationTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    @EnableCaching()
    public static class ConfigConfigurationTest {


        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "TestCacheBean")
        public CacheManager cacheManager() {
            CaffeineCacheManager caffeineCacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager("TestCache");
            return caffeineCacheManager;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("TestCacheBean")
    CacheManager cacheManager;

    @Mock
    MyDao dao;


    MyServiceImpl myServiceImpl ;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        myServiceImpl = new MyServiceImpl(dao);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCacheShouldPreventServiceCallDaoTwice() {
        //given
        Mockito.when(dao.findOne(1900L)).thenReturn(entity());
        //when
        CachedDTO conf1 = myServiceImpl.obtain(1900L);
        CachedDTO conf2 = myServiceImpl.obtain(1900L);
        //then
        Mockito.verify(dao, Mockito.times(1)).findOne(1900L);
    }
    ...
}
```

My service is calling dao, but dao is not cached only service [returning 'DTOs' are cached], yea maybe it is not so good practice but for now there is no other ways to refactor whole architecture.

For now i see that test is always calling service twice. Also I testes a lot of different scenarios how to build such test and always i'm getting same result, the cacheable seems to be ignored through whole process.

Test result:

> org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
>   dao.findOne(1900); Wanted 1 time:
>   -> at lalalalala.ConfigurationTest.testCacheShouldPreventServiceCallDaoTwice(ConfigurationTest.java:108)
>   But was 2 times. Undesired invocation:

@EDIT:

So, following the comments, I modified the test to use spring context, but result still is not changed.

@EDIT2:

For now problem is resolved, i put Mocked Dao and MyService to @Configuration and make MyService also a bean. Now it's working. 
I lost possibility to use mocked dao but i tested this in other way.

Comment: have you verified manually that your caching solution works and this is soley a testing issue?

Comment: There is no caching in your test. Using `MockitoJUnitRunner` basically renders your `ConfigConfigurationTest` and all the other spring annotations useless. You are only mocking the dao and creating an actual instance of the service.

Comment: M. Deinum, I modified code to met requirements

Comment: `myServiceImpl = new MyServiceImpl(dao);` it's not a spring instance, so don't expect Spring annotations to work.

Comment: So it must be created through @COnfiguration as a bean and then autowired?

Comment: You should define the cache annotation on a service implementation that you invoke in your test, not the `CacheManager` itself. You might want to have a look at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562642/caching-of-nested-cacheable-operation-via-springcache) I asked here on SO which is though more related to nested caching.

Comment: so for now i resolved my question, thanks, the problem was that i didnt put instance as bean through configuration.